# How to merge a simple Python app with a simple Flask app?

Tags: python, flask

to an existing application I have that does not have a UI, I'd like to visualise a chart while the application continues to produce its own results.

In other words I'd like to merge a Python app with a Flask interface?

For example the two next Python apps.

```
import time

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Loop", i)

    # I'd like to visualise i on a browser
```

Is it possible to use Flask and, instead of opening a window, see the Graph using a browser?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

# Send the data of the Python program to the Flask app
```

Comment: I wonder if you would be happier with a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org) rather than trying roll your own solution from the ground up.

Comment: My application works with sagemath (I used docker). I'm not sure if in that case it would be more difficult to setup and use it. But in general yes it would be great.

Comment: @v25. This is exactly what I was looking for. If you transfer this note to the Answer section, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention charts. You may wish to take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/roniemartinez/real-time-charts-with-flask) which lets you stream data from a function like yours to a chart.js chart on the frontend, via Server Sent Events. There used to be a corresponding blog, but that appears to be offline now. (EDIT: [found it](https://ron.sh/creating-real-time-charts-with-flask/))

Also if you're running this in prod (for example with gunicorn) you'll need to specify `eventlet` or `gevent` worker type in order to support multiple client connections.